# oracle sql : update select fields in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with HUNDREDS (literally) of fields.  I want to set them all to null except a 10 or so.  Obviously (?) doing an update statement and listing out all the fields seems to be a bad idea.   I am pretty new to SQL so would like some suggestions.

Comment: THat's realistically the right solution.  You could write some code that would generate the SQL statement by querying the data dictionary and then use dynamic SQL to process the `UPDATE` statement.  But unless you are planning to do this for a large number of tables, it'll be quicker and easier just to list the columns.  And if you have a table with hundreds of columns, you probably have a normalization issue that you need to address.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a bad idea to me.  In fact, it's the only one that's likely to work.

Comment: Well, ok.  I have no choice on the table normalization unfortunately.  But I will go ahead.

Comment: @lostinthebits: Sorry but i do not understand, only you want a query that update the fields from a table (except X rows) and show the updated rows?

Comment: More information about table structure, conditions on which you determine the records to be `NULL`ed would help.